# Datatable not calling javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

Hi i have a problem here in my datatable (http://www.datatables.net/)
here's my code.

```
enter code here
    <table id="example" width="100%"  border="0" class="display" >
        <thead>
        <tr align="center">
        <th>Function</th>
        <th>Location Name</th>
        <th>Route Id</th>
        <th>Stops</th>
        <th>Cbm</th>
        <th>Tons</th> 
        <th>Function</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        if(isset($load)>0){
            $id = 0;
            foreach($load as $key => $load){
            $id++;
        ?>
        <tr >
             <td>
                 <img **class="pencil_edit"** title="edit" src = "<?php echo                          base_url()."application/kookabura/images/pencil.png"; ?>">                    
             </td>
             <td><?php echo $load['name'];?></td>
             <td><?php echo $load['route_id'];?></td>
             <td><?php echo $load['stops'];?></td>
             <td><?php echo $load['cbm'];?></td>
             <td><?php echo $load['tons'];?></td>             
         </tr>

       <?php }
       }

       if(isset($_POST['date']) == ''){
          $date = date('Y-m-d');
       }else{
          $date = $_POST['date']; 
       }
      ?>
      </tbody>              
      </table>
```

now i have a function in javascript that is look like this the first 10 records can call this function but after i search for the next record for example record number 11 or after is sort the table it doesn't work. any idea? Tnx so much for the help hope you can understand what im saying here :D

```
    $( ".pencil_edit" )
            .click(function() {   
             alert('hello');
    });
```

Comment: Are your console getting error like `$ is undefined`?

Comment: Hi tnx for quick reply nothing happens when i click it no error display.

Comment: Can you give a little bit more information of problem

Comment: @user2861106 If you are retrieving data using AJAX then check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using AJAX then do as following way

**For jQuery 1.8 or above**

```
 $( document ).on('click', ".pencil_edit", function() {   
             alert('hello');
 });
```

**For jQuery 1.7 or below**

```
$( ".pencil_edit" ).live( "click", function() {
  alert( "Goodbye!" ); // jQuery 1.3+
});
```

Comment: Tnx Parixit $( "a.offsite" ).live save my day. Tnx so much for your help :D